# custom record level access in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I already implemented record level access through extending the class with **oRestricted** class and by assigning the permission to individual users to by updating _allow. I refer this URL for this approach,  https://orientdb.com/orientdb-supports-the-new-record-level-security/

but in that approach i need to update the **_allow** every time whenever a new record is added as well for new users (**oUser** class )  i need to update the existing records _allow column as well.

I am looking for a solution of custom record level access , so that i can include a Id column (custom property ) in oUser table  and same id column in other table and according to login user , can see the rows of custom table which matched with the id of oUser table.

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: Studio version : 3.0.6

OrientDB version : 3.0.6

Home Page : https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-studio

Copyrights : OrientDB LTD

License : Apache 2